# Get HTTP StatusCode in WebException

Tags: vb.net

I am wondering how can I get the HTTP Status returned after a WebException was thrown. I am calling for example a RestAPI to get a token and the Server returns a 401 and a Body in json Format telling me that access is denied. I would like to get the 401 but have not found a way to only get 401.

```
Catch ex As WebException
        Dim resp = New StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
        Dim errorNumber As Integer = CInt(ex.Status)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message & "  " & errorNumber)
        Console.WriteLine(resp & "  ")
        Return resp
```

Below is the console output I have for my code:

CInt(ex.Status) = "7" and the 
ex.message = "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

What I am looking for is to get the 401 or whatever the Server sends which would be equal to response.StatusCode

Comment: Should be able to get it from within the `ex.Response`

Comment: Thats what i thought too but for some reason StatusCode is not part of the ex.Response directly

Comment: You eventually figured it out. you had to cast to `HttpWebResponse` to get the status code

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to access the 401 directly

```
Dim ExResponse = TryCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
Console.WriteLine(ExResponse.StatusCode)
```

Comment: You should test `ex.Response`. It could be `Nothing`. In that case, you can use the `ex.Status` value which maps to a `WebExceptionStatus` enumeration. This can be useful to understand the exception if `HttpWebResponse` has never been initialized (this happens quite often when an exception is raised in this context).

Comment: I wasn’t looking for the web exception status but more for the code returned by restapi as it allows me to act on that. I control rest api and use it to return different 4xx based on why access is denied.

Comment: Well, the logic remains the same. Anyway, you could test it with `HttpClient()`. It can wrap a number of exceptions that `WebRequest/WebResponse` throw by default (any above `StatusCode` > 399).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I realise a few things while I search for a solution.

- `WebExceptionStatus` `enum` is not equivalent to http status code that the API you call returned. Instead it is a enum of possible error that may occour during a http call.
- The `WebExceptionStatus` error code that will be returned when you receive an error (400 to 599) from your API is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError` aka number 7 as int.
- When you need to get the response body or the real http status code returned from the api, first you need to check if `WebExceptionStatus.Status` is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`. Then you can get the real response from `WebExceptionStatus.Response` and read its content.

This is a C# code but you folow the same logic in VB.Net

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (WebException webException)
{
    if (webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;
        var responseText = "";
        using (var content = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = content.ReadToEnd(); // Get response body as text
        }
        int statusCode = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode; // Get the status code
    }

    // Handle other webException.Status errors
}
```